# 文字列を整数に変換できない。

Tags: python, python3

以下の様な文字列を含むデータがあり、1列目のみ整数にしたいのですが、うまくいかずエラーが表示エラーがでます。
なぜでしょうか。
よくわかりません。

データは以下。

```
[['id_NO', 'PROC_YM', 'CL_START', 'CL_STOP'], 
['000001', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
['000022', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'], 
['000333', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'], 
['004444', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'], 
['055555', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'], 
['666666', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'], 
['020000', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'], 
['003300', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'], 
['040044', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31']]
```

スクリプト

```
date['id_NO'] = date['id_NO'].astype(int)
print(date)
```

エラー内容

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `date[1:] = map(lambda x: [int(x[0])]+x[1:], date[1:])` という方法もあります。

Answer (score 2):

質問にある `.astype()` は `numpy.ndarray` および `pandas.Series`,`pandas.DataFrame` の method ですので、通常のリストには使用できません。

今回のデータはテーブルデータのようですので、`pandas.DataFrame` に変換してから、質問のmethodを使用するのが良いのかと思います。

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['id_NO', 'PROC_YM', 'CL_START', 'CL_STOP'],
        ['000001', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['000022', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['000333', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['004444', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['055555', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['666666', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['020000', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['003300', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31'],
        ['040044', '201912', '2019/12/1', '2019/12/31']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df['id_NO'] = df['id_NO'].astype(int)
print(df)
#    id_NO PROC_YM   CL_START     CL_STOP
#0       1  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#1      22  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#2     333  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#3    4444  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#4   55555  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#5  666666  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#6   20000  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#7    3300  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
#8   40044  201912  2019/12/1  2019/12/31
```

Comment: ＠magichan　　こちら理解できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

- データの書き方を見るに Python 組み込みの普通のリストでしょうか。Python の普通のリストはあくまで単なるリストであり、辞書や pandas DataFrame のように文字列を添え字として使いません。`date[1][0]` のように整数を添え字とします。あるいはこのリストを元に pandas DataFrame などに変換してから作業しても良いでしょう。
- このデータが pandas DataFrame や NumPy Array だったとしても、列の名前として `'id_NO'` 等が使われているのではなく、単に 1 行目に列名が入っているだけに見えます。適切に列の名前を設定する必要があります。

Comment: ＠nekketsuuu♦　なるほど勉強なりました。ありがとうございます。